# Magento 2.2.4 Implementing Bootstrap 4 Carousel to Homepage | JS seems to not be functioning

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get the Bootstrap 4 Carousel to work on my homepage and I've been facing an issues that seems like the JS may not be functioning. This is the way that I went about doing so.

I have consulted the Magento forums and a few very kind individuals attempted to help me resolve my issues. Unfortunately, I am still facing problems that I think even they are unable to fix. I will document the steps that I took and hopefully one of y'all can help me with this.

Created the following files

> /app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'bootstrap_bootstrap',
__DIR__
);
```

> /app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="bootstrap_bootstrap" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

> /app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  paths:{
    "jquery.bootstrap":"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  },
  shim:{
    'jquery.bootstrap':{
        'deps':['jquery']
    }
  }
};
```

> /app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="head">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
            <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <!-- Special block with necessary config is added on the page -->
    <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```

> /app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="head">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
            <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <!-- Special block with necessary config is added on the page -->
    <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
zelris@zelris.com [~/public_html/app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/view/frontend/layout]# cat default
default_head_blocks.xml  default.xml              
zelris@zelris.com [~/public_html/app/code/bootstrap/bootstrap/view/frontend/layout]# cat default_head_blocks.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
  <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
</head>
</page>
```

and I did in SSH

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content [Vendor]_[ModuleName]

php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I even verified that the module was enabled by doing

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

I added the following code to my homepage

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
requirejs(['jquery','jquery.bootstrap'], function(jQuery, jQueryBootstrap){
jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
<li class="active" data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Los Angeles</h3>
<p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Chicago</h3>
<p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>New York</h3>
<p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span> </a></div>
```

However, this still has not solved the issue of the slider not scrolling

I have checked the browser console and got the following error:
   http://website/pub/static/version1528395987/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery.bootstrap.js 404 (Not Found)

Can you guys please provide me with some more guidance? I would highly appreciate it.